# while trying to implement a Django chat app using channels after implement daphne and channels and set up ASGI the server dindt running in ASGI

Tags: django, django-templates, django-channels, asgi

[asgi.py file[installed apps[[after tring to fect the url it showing not fount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8pxe.png)  ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z01ia.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwIlL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdXwJ.png)

[after run the server it did run in the asgi while teing to get websocket url it showing not fount]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIC2C.[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIC2C.%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtr6N.png)png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).